# Where can I find precompiled Ogg,Speex and Vorbis libraries for iOS?

Tags: ios, ogg, speex, precompiled, oggvorbis

I need them compiled with i386, armv7 and also armv7s (the hardest to find).

I found a compilation for only Speex (which I haven't tested yet) here: http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2013/04/09/precompiled-speex-libraries-for-ios/

Does anyone know where I can get it or how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used:

1. Ogg & Vorbis from: https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZAQAudioPlayer/tree/master/Frameworks
2. Speex from: 
   https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZPrecompiledSpeex

And those works perfectly with armv7,armv7s and i386.

Answer (score 2):

see below links , you can get something related with this

check this `IDZAQAudioPlayer` example from github

https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZAQAudioPlayer

[vorbis](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/09/30/tutorial-open-source-on-ios-part-4-compiling-libvorbis/)
http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/09/30/tutorial-open-source-on-ios-part-4-compiling-libvorbis/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/files/opencore-amr/

http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2013/04/10/precompiled-flac-library-for-ios/

Comment: I've used:
https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZAQAudioPlayer/tree/master/Frameworks for Ogg&Vorbis and the link from my question and it worked. Thanks! (I can't award you but I'll do that when I would if this would be the best one)